# Pushing from ViewController to TabBarController takes delay

Tags: xcode, swift

In my project, I have ViewController A for login, when I pressed the login button it show ViewController B where I have four buttons. When I click button1, I have showSegue direct to TabBarController and it has two tabs. Same as button 2,3,4 I have showSegue directs to NavigationController. Actually this is the hierarchy of my TabBarController and NavigationController:

Click Button 1 to:

```
TabBarController -> 
Tab1 -> NavigationController -> ViewController1
Tab2 -> NavigationController -> ViewController2
```

Click Button 2,3,4 to:

```
NavigationController -> ViewController
```

I used storyboard in this project running Swift 2, Xcode 7. When I click each buttons, it takes almost 1-2 seconds delays especially on iPad real device. A bad user experience. It takes me a time to search some answers but sadly i didn't found a solution, that's why I asked it here..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have a time consumption code in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about using an async method to load your controllers when you press the buttons.

Try to use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

//Background Thread (Get your values - Run your requests)



dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

//Update the UI (Give values to your outlets)

    });
})
```

Comment: Actualy I'm just connecting the button1 to tabbarcontroller using showSegue in my storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

guys thanks for sharing your idea but i figured out the problems... Actually in my apps, I override one of navigation method which I changed the background of navigation bar with an image. The image is too large that's why it caused some delay before it present the next view. After changing the size of the image, it works properly now.